# updating firebase security rules through firebaseRef.set

Tags: javascript, firebase

Can I read and write security rules via

```
var firebaseRef = new Firebase('https://YOUR_FIREBASE.firebaseio.com/.settings/rules');
firebaseRef.set(rulesJson);
```

Answer (score 4):

No, but you can use a REST API to read or write security rules: https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest-api.html

```
curl https://SampleChat.firebaseio-demo.com/.settings/rules.json?auth=FIREBASE_SECRET
curl -X PUT -d '{ "rules": { ".read": true } }' https://SampleChat.firebaseio-demo.com/.settings/rules.json?auth=FIREBASE_SECRET
```